# Impact of crystal's ESR on the working of a crystal

Tags: oscillator, crystal, esr

I'd like to know how important the value of a crystal's ESR is for the working of the crystal at the right operating frequency.

I went through this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/379491/crystals-esr-or-frequency-stability-tolerance-which-is-more-of-a-priority) which asks for the priority between the crystal's ESR and stability, but I couldn't get clarity from the answers.

One of the answers states, "ESR has an effect on the pullability of the crystal and the power dissipation and probably jitter."

My question:

1. What does the pullability of the crystal mean in simple terms and why does it matter for ESR?
2. Also, why does ESR matter? How important is the value of ESR for the right oscillation of the crystal? Does higher ESR imply good oscillation, or does lower ESR?

Comment: These are basic terms explained in application notes of crystal manufacturers. And I think the answer you quote is wrong; I have never seen ESR in formulas for crystal pullability.

Comment: @Justme, yes. I did go through the application notes on these terms. But didn't get enough clarity

Comment: Which application notes you read? What was not clear in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'd like to know how important the value of a crystal's ESR is for the
> working of the crystal at the right operating frequency.*

It affects the oscillator operating frequency a little bit. Consider a simulation of a "10 MHz" crystal that I evolved some time ago. Here's the circuit: -

[image]

- \$V_{IN}\$ would be the raw logic gate driver voltage
- \$V_{OUT}\$ would feed the input of the logic gate in a Pierce oscillator
- Rs, Ls and Cs are the equivalent motional components of the crystal
- Cp is the electrical parallel capacitance of the crystal

If we plot the phase of \$V_{OUT}\$ we can see at what frequency we get 180° phase shift for various values of ESR (Rs): -

[image]

Summarising, for an ESR of 20 Ω we get an oscillation frequency of 10.001370 MHz. For an ESR of 80 Ω we get an oscillation frequency that is slightly higher at 10.001509 MHz (139 Hz higher).

> *What does the pullability of the crystal mean in simple terms and why
> does it matter for ESR?*

Pullability means how much we can make the oscillator run at a different frequency. For the graphs and simulation above, when ESR changes from 20 Ω to 80 Ω we can "pull" the oscillator frequency by 139 Hz.

But, remember, for a given crystal, we can't alter the internal ESR so this is not of any importance. We could add an external resistor of a few ohms but, this is missing the point; we use the "so-called" loading capacitors if we wish to "pull" the oscillation frequency. This is much more effective.

> *Also, why does ESR matter? How important is the value of ESR for the
> right oscillation of the crystal? Does higher ESR imply good
> oscillation, or does lower ESR?*

It doesn't matter in the bigger scheme of things because, for a given crystal, we "tune" the oscillator to where we want it (if we are concerned about having a very accurate frequency) by using the loading capacitors.

Also, as Rohat mentions in his answer (now deleted), the higher the value of ESR the more loop gain is needed by the logic gate (running linearly) to get successful oscillation. However, the loop gain is usually high enough to cope with large variations in ESR.

Comment: Just checking; isn't the Rs in the circuit called the motional resistance, and isn't the impedance of crystal at resonance called the ESR? That's how most crystal appnotes define them.

Comment: @Justme Rs is certainly the motional resistance but, as far as I'm aware it's called ESR too. When oscillating, the crystal exhibits net inductive reactance in series with Rs so, it makes sense to call Rs the effective series resistance. The problem might arise because different people/suppliers/do-gooders-who-think-they-know might use different terminology.

Comment: Thank you. In some appnotes, indeed they call the motional resistance (Rs) as ESR by ignoring shunt capacitance (Cp), and so by that definition of ESR at series resonant point Fs for Ls&Cs is Rs, measured out-of-circuit without load caps. The crystal is rarely used at Fs but at the inductive region, tuned by the load caps CL1 and CL2. Nice how your plot shows the actual system, not just the plot of crystal like many appnotes do.

Comment: @Justme to be honest, I think it's all a bit of a confusing mess what you find on-line. Even the big players don't seem to hit the mark and I can't think of one that mentions the 3rd order filtering needed to get oscillation. Of course, gate delays means you can make it work without considering 3rd order effects but, then you have to consider the variations of gate delay with temperature.